# Tensorflow and darknet cuda memory issue

Tags: python, tensorflow, yolo, resnet, darknet

I have 2 different custom trained models one is trained in Tensorflow (call this one model_1) (faster_rcnn_resnet50) and other is trained in darknet(call this one model_2) (yolov3).

model_1 for accident detection
model_2 for license plates detection

I have modified two scripts: object_detection.py (from tensorflow/models/research/object_detection) & darknet.py to meet my needs.

I load my model 1 using object_detection.py to detect accidents from a video and soon as I find any accident in any frame I save that frame and send it to darknet.py to detect license plates, but as soon as I pass my frame to darknet it starts loading the model and in between loading I get error:

```
CUDA status Error: file: ..\..\src\dark_cuda.c : cuda_make_array() : line: 357 : build time: Dec 11 2019 - 12:53:11
CUDA Error: out of memory
CUDA Error: out of memory: No error
```

My [object_detection.py](https://pastebin.com/13LRJEfZ)

My [darknet.py](https://pastebin.com/c6brrXEd)

Now I was wondering if there is any possible way to solve this issue without upgrading hardware.

My computer specs:

i7 6700HQ (with Intel HD graphics 530)

16 gigs of ram

GTX 950m 4GB edition

Edit: I tried loading model_1 on gpu and model_2 on cpu and I think it solved memory problem but now when ever and accident occurs all my python programs are forcedfully closed (not sure why) including cv2 video output and top of that I dont get any response from darknet.py (im.show())

```
[yolo] params: iou loss: mse (2), iou_norm: 0.75, cls_norm: 1.00, scale_x_y: 1.00
  95 route  91                                     ->    4 x   4 x 256
  96 conv    128       1 x 1/ 1      4 x   4 x 256 ->    4 x   4 x 128 0.001 BF
  97 upsample                 2x     4 x   4 x 128 ->    8 x   8 x 128
  98 route  97 36                                  ->    0 x   0 x   0
  99 Layer before convolutional layer must output image.: No error

C:\Users\Danial\Desktop\New folder\GUI>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the following fixes:

- Decrease the batch size in your `cfg/yolov3.cfg` file:

  ```
  batch=8
  ```
- Decrease the subdivisions size in your `cfg/yolov3.cfg` file:

  ```
  subdivisions=1
  ```
- Decrease the input size in your `object_detection.py` file:

  ```
  img_size = (320, 192)
  blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img, scale_factor, img_size, swapRB=True, crop=False)
  ```
- Decrease the input scale factor in your `object_detection.py` file:

  ```
  scale_factor = 1.0 / 255.0
  blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img, scale_factor, img_size, swapRB=True, crop=False)
  ```